# Try make a poll with getJSON() and jsonp the issue is the view is blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I try make a poll, basically I refresh my petition every 3s to the API using jsonp and getJSON the problem is my view also refresh at the same time and blink in the interface of the client (HTML), I have some like this

```
var chatbox = $("#chatbox");

       singleChatView();
        setInterval(function () {
            chatbox.empty();
            singleChatView();
        }, 1000);


        function singleChatView() {


            var chatid = localStorage.getItem('chatid');
            $.getJSON("http://myapi/?chatid=" + chatid + "&jsonp=?", function (chats) {

                console.log(chats);

                $.each(chats.DATA, function (key, c) {
                    $('.msgRecipientName').text(c.SENTBY.name);
                    if (c.SENTBY.id == userInfo.PROFILE.USERID) {
                        chatbox.append(
                            "<li class='msgThread group currentUser'>" +
                            "<div class='msgBalloon group'>" +
                            "<div class='msgHeader'>" +
                            "<div class='msgFull'>" + c.MESSAGE + "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='msgDate'>" +
                            formatDate(c.CREATEDON) +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</li>"
                        );
                    } else {
                        chatbox.append(
                            "<li class='msgThread group'>" +
                            "<div class='msgAuthor' style='background: #fff url(myapi/100_couple.png) 50% background-size: cover;'>" +
                            "<a ng-href=''>" +
                            "<span></span>" +
                            "</a>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='msgBalloon group'>" +
                            "<div class='msgHeader'>" +
                            "<div class='msgFrom'>" + c.SENTBY.name + "</div>" +
                            "<div class='msgFull'>" + c.MESSAGE + "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class='msgFrom'>" + c.SENTBY.name + "</div>" +
                            "<div class='msgDate'>" + formatDate(c.CREATEDON) + "</div>" +
                            "</li>"
                        );
                    }
                });


            });



        }
```

I don't have any idea how I can do this and void this issue with the view, can some one help me, all this is new for me thanks

Comment: what do you mean by the "view is blinking" ?

Comment: can you share your view?

Comment: I mean the view is Flicker or flashing

Comment: sorry shared my view you mean the coding ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the following.  The blink is most likely due to you clearing the chatbox and not putting anything in there until the ajax returns.  This version, aside from reducing the number of times the DOM is changed, also doesn't replace the chatbox until it has built all the html that should be in it.

```js
var chatbox = $("#chatbox");

//start the chat loop
singleChatView();

function singleChatView() {
  var chatid = localStorage.getItem('chatid');
  
  $.getJSON("http://myapi/?chatid=" + chatid + "&jsonp=?", function(chats) {
    console.log(chats);
    
    //collect the messages
    //if we update the page once, the browser has to do less work rendering
    //all the changes
    var messages = [];
    //keep track of the "c.SENTBY.name"
    //since you are doing a global selector and setter, the value will
    //end up being the last value you update all them to be anyway
    //no need to update multiple times
    var sendby = '';

    $.each(chats.DATA, function(key, c) {
      sentby = c.SENTBY.name;
      
      if (c.SENTBY.id == userInfo.PROFILE.USERID) {
        messages.push(
          "<li class='msgThread group currentUser'>" +
            "<div class='msgBalloon group'>" +
              "<div class='msgHeader'>" +
                "<div class='msgFull'>" + c.MESSAGE + "</div>" +
              "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='msgDate'>" + formatDate(c.CREATEDON) + "</div>" +
          "</li>"
        );
      } else {
        messages.push(
          "<li class='msgThread group'>" +
            "<div class='msgAuthor' style='background: #fff url(myapi/100_couple.png) 50% background-size: cover;'>" +
              "<a ng-href=''>" +
                "<span></span>" +
              "</a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='msgBalloon group'>" +
              "<div class='msgHeader'>" +
                "<div class='msgFrom'>" + c.SENTBY.name + "</div>" +
                "<div class='msgFull'>" + c.MESSAGE + "</div>" +
              "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='msgFrom'>" + c.SENTBY.name + "</div>" +
            "<div class='msgDate'>" + formatDate(c.CREATEDON) + "</div>" +
          "</li>"
        );
      }
    });
    
    //update the recipent with the last sent by, once
    $('.msgRecipientName').text(sentby);
    //replace all the chatbox text with the collected html that would have
    //otherwise been append one at a time
    chatbox.html(messages);
    
    //now that we've finished this iteration, start the next iteration after
    //a second
    setTimeout(singleChatView, 1000);
  });
}
```